# How to pull database from android mobile in MAC?

Tags: android, database, macos

I am developing an android app. I have tested the app in mobile and now i need to see the database of my app(i.e mobile database). I am using Mac and confused how to pull the database from the mobile and see it in SQLite browser.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: thanks for your comment i will try that.. do i need to insert ./ before adb in mac

Comment: yeah.. i tried it but it says not a directory

Comment: The exact path to the database varies by Android version.  I suggest the Eclipse file system browser in DDMS to obtain exactly the right path. I've found very few differences between the dev environments for Mac and PC, especially if you're using Cygwin on the PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to on a real device (unless it is rooted).  The data directories are protected against access by anything other than the owning app.

To get it off of the device you need to set up a method in your app to copy the database to somewhere that is accessible (like an SD card).  Following is code I've used to do that before:

```
public void backup() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                "yourDB.bak");

        if (!outputFile.exists()) 
             outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(data,
                "data/your.package.name/databases/yourDB");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i will try this and let you know and one simple question by using this method will i get the database in.db format?..

Comment: Yes, it is just a file copy with a name change.  You can change the extension to whatever you want (before you copy or after when you pull it off the card), it will still be your db file.  You can change `.bak` in the code I posted to `.db` and it will work, I just used some of my code that was for a file backup that achieves the purpose you were looking for.

Comment: Cheers Barak.. Its working awesome +1 for that.. yeah i changed .db before seeing your comment.. thanks a lot